# Matlab - Vectorizing nested loops when the inner loop depends on the outer ones

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I'm working on a function which takes an n-by-1 array (called "ts") as input and creates a n-by-n matrix (called "V"), where each element of V is either 0 or 1.

Now imagine "ts" as a plot: If one can connect an arbitrary point (e.g. ts(5)) with another arbitrary point (e.g. ts(47)) using a straight line without intersecting the time series, then the matrix elements V(5,47) and V(47,5) should be 1. If the two points can't be connected without intersecting the time series then the corresponding elements in the matrix should be 0. This is supposed to be done for all possible pairs of points in "ts".

Here's the function: It works, but it's very inefficient (especially because of the three nested loops). Is there a way to vectorize this code?

```
function V = someFunction(ts)
len = length(ts);
V = zeros(len, len);
for a = 1:len,
   for b = 1:len,
       intersection = [];
       for c = min(a,b)+1 : max(a,b)-1,
           t_a = a;
           y_a = ts(a);
           t_b = b;
           y_b = ts(b);
           t_c = c;
           y_c = ts(c);

           if (y_c < y_b + (y_a - y_b) * ((t_b - t_c) / (t_b - t_a))),
               intersection = [intersection; 0];
           else
               intersection = [intersection; 1];
           end
       end
       if all(intersection==0),
           V(a,b) = 1;
       end
   end
end
end
```

Comment: You're growing intersection, yuo should preallocate it.

Comment: @OlegKomarov - it can be removed altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

several things:

1. no need to create array `intersection` the moment you hit the `else` clause you know `V(a,b)` is zero.
2. Since `V` is symmetric, you can compute only `.5*n*(n-1)` entries instead of `n^2` (same O(n^2), but still far less).
3. Another observation made by [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180721/oleg-komarov) is: "you do not need to perform any check if the segment is 3 points long, in which case there cannot be any intersection by construction"

New code

```
V = ones(len,len); % default for all
for a = 1:(len-3),
   for b = (a+3):len,
      for c = min(a,b)+1 : max(a,b)-1,
          t_a = a;
          y_a = ts(a);
          t_b = b;
          y_b = ts(b);
          t_c = c;
          y_c = ts(c);

          if (y_c < y_b + (y_a - y_b) * ((t_b - t_c) / (t_b - t_a))),
              % do nothing
          else
              V(a,b) = 0; % intersect
              V(b,a) = 0;
              break; % stop the inner loop the moment an intersection was found
          end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: @Shai, well the original code always produces a symmetric matrix, while yours does not. Try running both with the input `ts = [-1 5 20 -1]`.

Comment: You can also include my remark (from my deleted answer) that segments of three points cannot intersect by construction, thus having `a = 1:len-3` and `b = a+3:len`.

Comment: @OlegKomarov - I incorporated your remark to the code. Thanks.